# Bootbox example not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

I have an problem I cannot run this simple Bootbox example on my localhost. Does anyoone know why I cant? Thanks :) I am using wamp server and other pages works correctly with bootstrap but this bootbox I am using first time and there is no Alert message after hitting button.

My code here:
http://pastebin.com/Mctq19Ya

```
             <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8">
                        <title>My page</title>


                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="https://raw.github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/v2.5.1/bootbox.min.js"></script>
                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
                            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <input type="button" class="btn-success btn-lg" id="boxik" value="button" />
                        <script>
                            jQuery("#boxik").on("click", function() {
                            bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
                            console.log("Alert Callback");
                                 });
                                });
                        </script>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: Make sure all the file links you have set in the document work.

Comment: All included links are working

Comment: Try updating jquery to 1.11.x

Comment: still not working, do you have any working example? Could you post it here please?

Comment: Nope check the google console if any errors are logged.

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't) load the Bootbox JavaScript file directly from Github; it's not served correctly (nor is it intended to be used in that manner). Download one of the versions linked to here: http://bootboxjs.com/#download

Answer (score 0):

try by putting,
script src="bootstrap.min.js"
after bootstrap links...
because bootstrap and styles should load first. Then only 'js' files